# Eclipse Export Product not possible

Tags: java, eclipse, export, product, headless

I tried to make a headless Eclipse RCP because I want to launch it through a C file with JNI. I created a plug-in project, set the correct settings in MANIFEST.MF and created Headless.product. Everything works, also Application.java, but when I tried to export the .product to have the executable file, it gave me an error. So I tried with an existing project from [this](http://codeandme.blogspot.com/2012/02/creating-headless-application.html) tutorial (just in case the problem wasn't in the settings) and it gave me the same error:

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
 Software being installed: Headless Example 0.0.0 
 (com.codeandme.headless.headless 0.0.0)
 Missing requirement for filter properties ~= $0: Headless Example 
 0.0.0 (com.codeandme.headless.headless 0.0.0) requires 
 'com.codeandme.headless.headless_root.gtk.linux.x86_64 [1.0.0]' but 
 it could not be found
```

[This is the screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRS3J.png)

(Where com.codeandme.headless is the name of the project)

Now, what should I do to make the export possible? Anything to do with `org.eclipse.equinox.executable`? And if yes, where and how can I add it?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you get this error? It doesn't look like anything that Export RCP what say

Comment: When I go to Headless.product, in the overview tag, there's "Eclipse Product export wizard" under "Exporting". Then I have to choose a folder in which I save the executable file but it gives me that error.

Comment: There is a similar problem report on the Eclipse forums [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/162005/). Their problem seemed to be something to do with the target platform.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message:

```
Missing requirement for filter properties ~= $0: Application 0.0.0 (org.acme.project.application 0.0.0) requires  'org.acme.project.other 1.2.3' but  it could not be found
```

For some reason this error (also) means, that `org.acme.project.other` is present... twice.

So in your case, open the "Content" tab of the "Target Editor" and make sure that `com.codeandme.headless.headless_root.gtk.linux.x86_64` is not present in two distinct versions. This bundle might be inside a feature, so it might be a bit hard to find where the second version came from.